# Why is this not a Lattice?

Tags: lattice-orders

I am having some trouble understanding lattices. The following is defined as **not** being a lattice:

$$S = \{ \{\}, \{y\}, \{x\}, \{x,y,z\}, \{a,x,y,z\}, \{b,x,y,z\} \}$$

I understand that a lattice is a poset for each exists a unique largest element and a unique smallest element (least upper bound and greatest lower bound).

Therefore, is the above not a lattice because we have: $\{a,x,y,z\}$ and $\{b,x,y,z\}$?

Comment: Is the order at hand $\subseteq$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. ⊆ is the order.

Comment: You wrote "*I understand that a lattice is a poset for each exists a unique largest element and a unique smallest element (least upper bound and greatest lower bound)*". The part outside of the brackets doesn't really make sense. A lattice is a poset in which $\sup (\alpha ,\beta)$ exists for any elements $\alpha ,\beta$ in the lattice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a lattice, for any $\alpha ,\beta$, $\sup (\alpha ,\beta )$ exists.

If your set were to be a lattice, what would be $\sup (\{a,x,y,z\},\{b,x,y,z\})$?

If $\sup (\{a,x,y,z\},\{b,x,y,z\})$ existed in $S$, then there would exist upperbounds for $\{\{a,x,y,z\},\{b,x,y,z\}\}$, but none exist. Therefore $\sup (\{a,x,y,z\},\{b,x,y,z\})$ doesn't exist. Hence $(S,\subseteq )$ is not a lattice.

It is true that $\varnothing$ is the greatest lower bound for $S$ because it is the *only* lower bound for $S$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand...

Comment: @user1796218 I added some stuff to the answer. Basically I'm proving you're right about what you said in your question.

Comment: Thank you! Stupid question: what is sup()?

Comment: @user1796218 $\sup (\alpha, \beta)$ is the least upperbound for the set $\{\alpha ,\beta\}$.

Comment: OK, thank you. What do you mean with "sup({a,x,y,z},{b,x,y,z}) doesn't exist"? As, that there can either ever only be one least upper bound? So, either {a,x,y,z} or {b,x,y,z}? Since we have both {a,x,y,z} and {b,x,y,z}, and since these are both the largest elements, then S cannot be a lattice?

Comment: @user1796218 There are two reasons for $\sup$ to not exist. Either there isn't any upper bound or there isn't a least upper bound. In our case there is no upper bound at all. Your argument has the right idea, but you're confused about somethings. For instance $\{a,x,y,z\}$ can't be the "largest element" of $S$ because it isn't bigger than $\{b,x,y,z\}$.