# Is polynomial ring a lattice?

Tags: polynomials, lattice-orders

My prof says it's not. But I can't find a polynomial pair of $f,g$ such that $max(f,g)$ or $min(f,g)$ is not in $R[x]$. Define uniform order: $f\leq g$,if for all $x, f\leq g $.

Comment: How are you defining the underlying order?

Comment: What is "uniform order"?

Comment: Consider $f=-g$ where $f$ takes at least negative value and at least one positive value. **Edit:** You can also take [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299483/why-is-this-not-a-lattice#comment650699_299492) comment as a hint.

Comment: you mean this makes a non differentiable function hence not a polynomial?

Comment: No,thing like that.Let $f(x)=x$,for all $x$and $g=-f$.What is $\max(f,g)$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the ordering you give forms a lattice [over the set of functions continuous in an interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657711/lattice-of-continuous-functions), so the problem must be that a supremum isn't a polynomial.

As git suggests in a comment above, you can take $f(x) = x, g(x) = - x$. I claim that not only is there no supremum of these two functions, but in fact there is no polynomial greater than both of them under your ordering. Can you see why?